# Cant change button text after i get the response

Tags: jquery, html

What I want to do is when I click on the button "Deactivate Account", after I get the response I want to change the buttons html to "Activate Account" (from Deactivate Account) and put class `btn-success`.

When i type _Admin.temp.button.html("Activate") it tells me this error

> _Admin.temp.button is not a function*

But when I type in console `_Admin.temp.button` it gives me the right clicked button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="_Admin.changeStatus(82,0, this)">Deactivate Account</button>
```

here is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger"  onclick="_Admin.changeStatus({{$user -> id}},0, this)">Deactivate Account</button>

var _Admin=
{
inputs:{},
temp:{},
changeStatus: function(id, status, html)
    {
        this.inputs.id=id;
        this.inputs.status=status;
        this.temp.button = html;
        this.request('change-status','change_status');
    }`

    case 'change_status':
        if(data == true)
        {
            _Admin.response({result: true, msg: "Statusi u ndryshua me sukses"});
            _Admin.temp.button;
        }
```

btw this is not the exact code, I did reduce it a bit so its easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html()` is not a method on a DOM element. Try wrapping the element in a jQuery object:

```
$(_Admin.temp.button).html("Activate")
```